# Looking for a pattern with conditions

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a huge file in which I want to look for a word, say **`pattern`**. I'm trying to illustrate my case with an example.

Suppose I have in my file somewhere

```
Sample-pattern="abc"
```

I want to write a script that will echo `Sample` and `abc` i.e. the word preceding the hyphen and the word inside the quotes

So if there was

```
Sample2-pattern="xyz"
```

it would echo `Sample2` and `xyz`

Note that there might be the word `pattern` in that file elsewhere. But if the word `pattern` has anything except hyphen before it, the script should ignore it. For example, if there is

```
Sample3pattern.....
```

it should ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input `file.txt`:

```
Sample-pattern="abc"
Sample2-pattern="xyz"
Sample3pattern="def"
```

The following `sed` script will produce this output:

```
$ sed -E -n -e '/-pattern/ s/^([^-]*)-[^=]*="([^"]*)"/\1 \2/p' file.txt
Sample abc
Sample2 xyz
```

The `sed` script above prints all text before the first `-` character in a line, AND all text inside double-quotes after the first `=` character on a line.  It doesn't print lines which don't match the regexes (both of them - the `/-pattern/` address spec and the `s///` search and replace).

NOTE: It uses the `-E` option of `sed` to enable extended regular expressions.  This works with GNU, *BSD, Mac OS X, and some other versions of `sed`....it is better to use `-E` than the GNU-ish `-r` option which does the same thing but is not implemented in Mac OS X's version of `sed`.  `-E` is likely to become a POSIX standard in the not-too-distant future.

a Basic regular expression version would be:

```
sed -n -e '/-pattern/ s/^\([^-]*\)-[^=]*="\([^"]*\)"/\1 \2/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to GNU `grep` (the default on Linux), you can do:

```
grep -Po '\w+-pattern="[^"]+' file
```

The `-E` enables Extended Regular Expressions which give us `\S` which matches any non-whitespace character. The `-o` makes `grep` print only the matched portion of the line. The regex itself looks for one or more non-space characters (`\S+`), then `-pattern="` and then one or more non-`"` characters (`[^"]+`). So, give a file like this:

```
$ cat file
Sample-pattern="abc"
Sample2-pattern="xyz"
Sample3pattern="foo"
```

The `grep` command would return this:

```
$ grep -Eo '\S+-pattern="[^"]+' file 
Sample-pattern="abc
Sample2-pattern="xyz
```

You can then pass it through `sed` to remove `-pattern="`:

```
$ grep -Eo '\S+-pattern="[^"]+' file | sed 's/-pattern="/ /'
Sample abc
Sample2 xyz
```

Comment: I want to print the word before the hyphen, not the word "pattern"

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea ah, OK, and do you only want the first word (defined by space) or the whole line before `-pattern`?

Comment: just the word before the hyphen, not the whole line

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea OK, see updated answer.